# Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale past a single process

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, memory-leaks

Good day guys here is my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: false,
maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15,
cookie:{
    secure: true
       }
}));
```

this code always returns on my log a :

> Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale past a single process.

i tried googling about it but i don't seems to understand some tutorials .
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope this would help to someone who's struggling the same problem as mine .
Just dug it by myself .

```
//-momery unleaked---------
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(session({
cookie:{
    secure: true,
    maxAge:60000
       },
store: new RedisStore(),
secret: 'secret',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: false
}));

app.use(function(req,res,next){
if(!req.session){
    return next(new Error('Oh no')) //handle error
}
next() //otherwise continue
});
```

Comment: would be more helpful if you do a little bit explaining!!...since you use RedisStore(), what about Mongodb??

Comment: The thing is that it not really safe to store the session data in the memory. It not encrypted or protected in any way.Also, every time when the server is restarted all the session data will be gone and the users will have to login again. Furthermore, you cant scale your app in the future because the session data is stored locally in the memory and cant be accessed by the other instance of the app running either remotely or on the same host as a separate process Using external session storage helps in solving these problems. Redis is a database that can do exactly that. MongoDB will also work.

Answer (score 24):

Using `cookie-session` instead of `express-session` solved this issue for me.

You store the session on the client and not on the server with cookies.

Simply:

1. Install it with `npm install cookie-session`
2. Change

   > <s>`var session = require('express-session');`</s>
   >
   > to `var session = require('cookie-session');`

Answer (score 5):

It's all about storing sessions, you should add a storing system that store sessions into your database. This help your app to manage sessions.

For example, in mongodb you can use connect-mongo, you should found a store package and for other databases.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```

Comment: what if i don't use Mongo?

Comment: You have some choices https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/README.md#compatible-session-stores

Answer (score 0):

The default MemoryStore for express-session will lead to a memory leak due to it haven't a suitable way to make them expire.

Use the below package to fix the issue.

```
npm i memorystore
```

Pass the express-session store into memorystore to create a MemoryStore constructor.

```
const session = require('express-session')
const MemoryStore = require('memorystore')(session)

app.use(session({
    cookie: { maxAge: 86400000 },
    store: new MemoryStore({
      checkPeriod: 86400000 // prune expired entries every 24h
    }),
    resave: false,
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))
```

for more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/memorystore