# Application is running in local environment but failing on Heroku

Tags: heroku, cloud9

My app is working fine on my Cloud9 workspace but not on Heroku.
I am connected to the mLab database.
I have also tried by switching database but it's not working.

**Error Logs:**

```
hacker8878:~/workspace/YelpCamp/v10 (master) $ heroku run node app.js
Running node app.js on ⬢ murmuring-brushlands-13115... up, run.5176 (Free)
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
The YelpCamp server has started
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:17:21)
    at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:880:3)
    at connectOp (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:269:3)
    at executeOperation (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:260:10)
    at Promise (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:427:12)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:424:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:208:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:19:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882535/warning-connect-session-memorystore-is-not-designed-for-a-production-environm). It looks like you're trying to use an Express session store with mongoose, so I'm guessing you're using connect-mongo. Make sure you haven't typo-ed the `store` property in your `express.session()` call.

I'd also recommend checking out [connect-mongodb-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongodb-session) as an alternative to connect-mongo. It's easier to work with out of the box and less error prone.